# allocating secure tunnels as TTY but in background

Tags: ssh, tty, ssh-tunnel

To run sudo I need to force a tty, but I can't allocate one in the background, unless I say `-t -t`. Any chance you could explain what the difference is?

```
#fails
ssh -t host1 'sudo command' &
ssh -t host2 'sudo command' &
wait
```

The above fails "fails with you must run a tty" and

```
#works
ssh -t -t host1 'sudo command' &
ssh -t -t host2 'sudo command' &
wait
```

works? does it mean a tty within a tty?

Answer (score 0):

The manual page for `ssh` explains that:

> `-t`
>   Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  **Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.**

If you run the command in background, the local tty will not stay attached to the command and therefore it is not allocated remote with a single `-t`. On the other hand, using two `-tt` will finally force the allocation.

Comment: So for every layer child process or backgrounded process you need an additional `-t` request? so a background + a background needs `-ttt`?